# php switch wrong response when value is zero

Tags: php

Whats wrong? this switch prints the second case, why?

```
$myvalue = 0;

switch ($myvalue)
{
    case ($myvalue >= 0 )and($myvalue <= 2 ): 
        echo "case 1";echo "<br>";
        break;
    case ($myvalue >= 3 )and($myvalue <= 12 ): 
        echo "case 2";echo "<br>";
        break;
    case ($myvalue >= 13):echo "3";
        echo "case 3";echo "<br>";
        break;
}
```

Comment: with "&&" the responce is the same , case 2  :s

Comment: Seems a lot more like a Case for an IF if you ask me (pun intended)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're switching on a value of `0`, which is "falsy". So the first case that evaluates to **false** is the one that's running.

A switch statement compares the result of the case conditions to the value used at the top. So if you want the first *true* case to be the one that runs, you need to use `switch (true)`:

```
$myvalue=0;

switch (true) {
    case ($myvalue >= 0 )and($myvalue <= 2 ): 
        echo "case 1";echo "<br>";
        break;
    case ($myvalue >= 3 )and($myvalue <= 12 ): 
        echo "case 2";echo "<br>";
        break;
    case ($myvalue >= 13):echo "3";
        echo "case 3";echo "<br>";
        break;
}
```

See https://3v4l.org/cBJa8

As mentioned in a comment, you might also want to refactor this to use `&&` rather than `and`. It won't make any difference in this case, but there are some subtle changes that you might run into later.

Comment: is this still the case if strict_types is enabled (in that, OP code stays same, add strict_types and all gravy?)?

Comment: @treyBake I'm not sure why strict_type would have any effect - as far as I know it's only used to control the type conversion for scalar type hints in functions

Comment: @iainn ah yeah, so you're right! I for some reason assumed it would just execute all the PHP using strict type comparison, so, my theory was that by just declaring that it takes out the loose false-y comparison - but a quick test tells me otherwise :) the more ya know :)

Comment: @treyBake There has actually been some decent discussion about a "strict" switch statement, but it hasn't got any further than a proof of concept, and then a lot of trying to agree what the syntax would look like: https://externals.io/message/102251

Comment: @iainn interesting read, I like the `case strict ...` syntax idea, or the passing it as a flag option - either way, maybe we'll see it added at some point this year, would be really nice to have :)